# What is the difference between SDP and VMA?

Tags: sockets, tcp, infiniband, rdma

As known for Infiniband or RoCE-Ethernet we can use:

- [**VMA**](http://www.mellanox.com/page/software_vma?mtag=vma) - Voltaire Messaging Accelerator (VMA) Mellanox's Messaging Accelerator (VMA) boosts performance for message-based and streaming applications... The result is a reduction in latency by as much as 300% and an increase in application throughput by as much as 200% per server...
- [**SDP**](http://www.mellanox.com/pdf/whitepapers/SDPCluster2006.pdf) -  Sockets Direct Protocol (SDP) is a byte stream protocol that utilizes the capabilities of the InfiniBand fabric to transparently achieve performance gains for existing socket-based networked applications.

Also - Page 9: http://www.informatix-sol.com/docs/TCP_bypass_overview.pdf

[image]

And known, that both SDP and VMA use RDMA-Verbs and can be used for already compiled binary of program as (libpreload) LD_PRELOAD: http://www.informatix-sol.com/low-latency.html

> As with Openonload, SDP and Mellanox's VMA all preload to accelerate
>   an existing TCP/IP socket program. Openonload retains the TCP/IP
>   protocol so can be used single ended. SDP and VMA both map to VERBS so
>   must be deployed on both ends of the wire.

Also get image from:

- Page 15 figure 2-1: http://lists.openfabrics.org/pipermail/general/attachments/20081016/3fe4fd45/attachment.obj
- Page 76: http://ircc.fiu.edu/download/sc13/Infiniband_Slides.pdf

[image]

But if SDP and VMA both:

- bypasses TCP/IP-stack
- uses RDMA-verb
- must be deployed on both ends of the wire
- can be used for already compiled binary of program as (libpreload), run program.bin as: `LD_PRELOAD=libsdp.so program.bin` or `LD_PRELOAD=libvma.so program.bin`

then why such a big difference in speed (latency and bandwidth)?

- **VMA has latency in 2.5 times lower than SDP**
- **VMA has bandwidth in 1.8 times bigger than SDP**

Comment: Isn't SDP supposed to be used in Java? Whereas VMA is a socket-level implementation of RDMA. It seems to me they are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JC1 SDP is not related to Java. SDP and VMA both can be used in C/C++/C#/Java by using `sockfd=socket(AF_INET_SDP,SOCK_STREAM,0);` instead of `sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);`. Also SDP/VMA can be used without change and recompile source coude with standard `socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)` - by running program as `LD_PRELOAD=libsdp.so program.bin`. SDP and VMA both map to RDMA-VERBS. "The Sockets Direct Protocol (SDP) is a transport-agnostic protocol to support stream sockets over Remote Direct Memory Access (RDMA) network fabrics." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockets_Direct_Protocol